# Having a problem with 2SXC Blog 3.3 on DNN 9.2.1

Tags: 2sxc

After installing App 10.1 and blog 3.3 I'm getting this error on my first post.

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at ASP._Page_Portals_1_2sxc_Blog_App__Post_Details_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\vhosts\enjoythisworld.com\httpdocs\Portals\1\2sxc\Blog App_Post Details.cshtml:line 7 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.RazorEngine.Render(TextWriter writer) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy Content Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 65 at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.RazorEngine.RenderTemplate() in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy Content Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 92 at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.EngineBase.Render() in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\SexyContent\Engines\EngineBase.cs:line 92 at ToSic.SexyContent.SxcInstance.Render() in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\SexyContent\SxcInstance_Render.cs:line 58

The original demo content loaded fine. I've deleted the sample content and tried a test blog. I see several references to `c:\projects\2sxc-dnn742`. This is DNN 9.2.1

Is that a problem referencing the developer's local drive? Is there some compatibility issue?

Comment: I've installed blog app on 2sxc 10.1 and it's working properly. The only difference is that I have DNN 9.3.2 on a private server.
I suggest you report it to https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues

Comment: I believe the problem is the deleted demo-items. One or two are in use on the views to show when nothing has been added yet. I suggest you remove/re-install or check the views if any are referencing a "demo item" which doesn't exist any more.